# OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long in JSON FILE (python)

Tags: python, request

i have this error - OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long:

what is the best way to work around this?

```
import requests
import json
import codecs

url = 'https://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS314en-GB.json'
response = requests.get(url)

text = response.text

data = json.load(codecs.open(text, encoding='utf8'))

print('data', data)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `codecs.decode` instead of `codecs.open`? It doesn't seem like `text` is a file.

Comment: So you're expecting the entirety of this response from a government website to be a valid filename on your computer?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just leave out the first 3 Bytes, which indicate the BOM:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS314en-GB.json'
response = requests.get(url)

text = response.content[3:]
data = json.loads(text)
print(data)
```

More dynamically would to lookup the correct BOM and strip if off the data:

```
BOMS = [
    codecs.BOM,
    codecs.BOM_BE,
    codecs.BOM_LE,
    codecs.BOM_UTF8,
    codecs.BOM_UTF16,
    codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE,
    codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE,
    codecs.BOM_UTF32,
    codecs.BOM_UTF32_BE,
    codecs.BOM_UTF32_LE,
]

url = 'https://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS314en-GB.json'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.content

for BOM in BOMS:
    if data.startswith(BOM):
        data = json.loads(data[len(BOM):])
        break
print(data)
```

Out:

```
{'FHRSEstablishment': {'Header': ...
```

Comment: This only worked because this particular response happened to have a utf-8 BOM at the front. It is not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

`codecs.open` is used to open files. You used the entirety of the website's JSON response as that file name. `requests` already knows about JSON and you can just have it do the decode for you

```
import requests
import json
import codecs

url = 'https://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS314en-GB.json'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print('data', data)
```

This is far better than making some unwarranted assumptions about how the JSON from this particular web site is encoded.

Comment: This raises an exception for me

Comment: @MauriceMeyer - it works for me. This is a broken website that doesn't return content encoding information in its response header. And just as bad, it does return a BOM. I assumed that the requests json code would default to utf-8 (the default encoding for json) and deal with any BOM. Perhaps it is using the system's default encoding and yours isn't utf-8.